# In Perl, how do I remove consecutive pairs of characters from a string?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a string containing pairs of characters and I would like to replace each run by a single character. How can I do that?

---

This is a [question](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_do_I_remove_cons) from the [official FAQ](http://faq.perl.org/). We're [importing the perlfaq to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/can-we-import-the-perlfaq-into-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 9):

(This is the [official perlfaq answer](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_do_I_remove_cons), minus any subsequent edits)

You can use the substitution operator to find pairs of characters (or runs of characters) and replace them with a single instance. In this substitution, we find a character in `(.)`. The memory parentheses store the matched character in the back-reference `\g1` and we use that to require that the same thing immediately follow it. We replace that part of the string with the character in `$1`.

```
s/(.)\g1/$1/g; # 5.10 or later
s/(.)\1/$1/g;  # earlier versions
```

We can also use the transliteration operator, `tr///`. In this example, the search list side of our `tr///` contains nothing, but the c option complements that so it contains everything. The replacement list also contains nothing, so the transliteration is almost a no-op since it won't do any replacements (or more exactly, replace the character with itself). However, the `s` option squashes duplicated and consecutive characters in the string so a character does not show up next to itself

```
my $str = 'Haarlem';   # in the Netherlands
$str =~ tr///cs;       # Now Harlem, like in New York
```

Comment: When did that `g` (in `\g1`) slip in there? It's not in the POD for 5.12.1 but I can see it in github. Is it a future (5.13+) thing?

Comment: The `\g` construct was introduced in `5.10.0`. From `perl5100delta`: *A new syntax `\g{N}` or `\gN` where "N" is a decimal integer allows a safer form of back-reference notation as well as allowing relative backreferences.*

Comment: There is no need, beyond *REQUIRING* 5.10, to use that over \1 in this answer.

Comment: @MkV, There is a reason that `\gN` and `\g{N}` were added to the language. The original way had the mis-feature that it is nearly **identical** to how you would enter an Octal escape. Since this document is mostly for new Perl programmers, it makes perfect sense to show them the safer way first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=~ s/(.)\1+/$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from [perlfaq4](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/pod/perlfaq4.pod#How_do_I_remove_consecutive_pairs_of_characters?) from the last stable release:

How do I remove consecutive pairs of characters?

(contributed by brian d foy)

You can use the substitution operator to find pairs of characters (or runs of characters) and replace them with a single instance. In this substitution, we find a character in (.). The memory parentheses store the matched character in the back-reference \1 and we use that to require that the same thing immediately follow it. We replace that part of the string with the character in $1.

```
s/(.)\1/$1/g;
```

We can also use the transliteration operator, tr///. In this example, the search list side of our tr/// contains nothing, but the c option complements that so it contains everything. The replacement list also contains nothing, so the transliteration is almost a no-op since it won't do any replacements (or more exactly, replace the character with itself). However, the s option squashes duplicated and consecutive characters in the string so a character does not show up next to itself

```
my $str = 'Haarlem';   # in the Netherlands
$str =~ tr///cs;       # Now Harlem, like in New York
```

Comment: If possible it would be great for the author to post the answer himself (i.e. brian should post his new answer from stable or master).

Comment: @Ether and @MkV brian and I are posting these questions using http://stackoverflow.com/users/532928/perlfaq using the version available on http://faq.perl.org/ The questions are posted using the `perlfaq` account so that we do not gain rep from them and answers are marked CW so that it is easier to improve answers. I do not see much of a point in posting almost identical versions of the answers (for rep gain) instead of editing the existing one.

Comment: @Sinan: ok, I misunderstood; I was under the impression that there was a radically different answer for some questions in blead than the "officially published" version. If the differences are subtle I agree with simply editing the existing response.